# Do artifacts exist as partial files in JFrog Artifactory while upload is in progress?

Tags: upload, artifactory

If I am uploading an artifact into JFrog Artifactory via Teamcity plugin Spec Schema

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "pattern": "/home/teamcity/.m2/temp/abcdef-*.tar.gz",
      "target": "abc-repository-xyz/"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, it's an archive file of 500MB, takes around 25 sec to upload (according to teamcity build logs).

During this time duration of 25sec, does the artifact exist as a partial file or only when it is a complete file, it is listed in the Artifactory repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is buffered in Artifactory until fully uploaded (there are some more complex scenarios), and it visible only once upload is complete.

Fully uploaded means that Artifactory updated the database with the file's metadata once the file is stored.

Comment: So that means it won't be available/visible to download as well until fully uploaded , right? let's say I am downloading via JFrog CLI `jfrog rt dl --spec=downloadSpec.json --url="url" --user="user" --password="pwd" --sort-by=updated --sort-order=desc --limit=1`

Comment: Correct. It will not be available :-)